# Conversion to bibtex

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I have a substantial bibliography in APA format at the end of my dissertation proposal.
I would like to reformat the proposal into latex (Currently Google Docs), and I was wondering if there is a way to automatically generate bibtex from well formatted APA references.

Please advise.

Comment: Your best bet is bibliographical management software that can import from Google Docs and then export a proper BibTeX file.  I have no experience with the first requirement (can anything do that?!), but exporting BibTeX is a fairly common feature since the it is a very plain format.

Comment: I've also seen (long ago) `text2bib` (or `txt2bib`) applications online.  They were not particularly useful in my case, but they did get most of the job done.  However, my bibliography was not in APA, so maybe you'd have better luck.

Comment: Is the bibliography already hard-coded to APA specs?

Comment: Yes, it is a formal APA references list.

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck with http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/ for this sort of task (book chapters combined into a singe edited volume). It may also be possible to use Zotero (zotero.org), which can parse references into its own format and export bibtex.